# javascript inside InfoWindow

Tags: openinfowindowhtml

I'm having this issue 
I would like to open an InfoWindow to which I set a given html content as a string
but it happens that this html content has some JavaScript functions that needs to be executed when the HTML is rendered inside the google.maps.InfoWindow object.

Is there a way to do that?

for more details, the concrete case is this.
As part of my html string I have a javaScript function for rendering graphics from google.visualization. API 
therefore in my java script y set the content to the infowindow in this way.

```
myHtml = 'html code with java script function fro rendering google.visualization......';
info = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
info.setContent(myHtml)
```

as a result, I can correctly see the HTML rendered inside the InfoWindow, but without the graphs rendered.

is there another way to do this? I've tried it in different browsers with no possitive results.

thanks in advance.